# So/Neither am/do I. Which one is correct for the following questions

Tags: grammar

She is happy. ___ am I.

She is unhappy. ___ am I.

She is never unhappy. ___ am I.

She likes pizza. ___ do I.

She dislikes pizza. ___ do I.

Answer (score 1):

Here they are:

> As am I. <-- "So" could work, but "as" just sounds better (to me, at least).
>
> As am I. <-- See above.
>
> Neither am I. <-- Agreeing about a negation.
>
> So do I. <-- Agreeing with what "she" likes.
>
> So do I. <-- You're not negating anything, you're agreeing... Thus, you wouldn't use "neither" in this circumstance. (Note that you would use "neither" if she had said "I do not like pizza" because you are agreeing with the negation of "like.")